# AppEngine NDB Query return different Results

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a query in my live app that has gone "odd"...

Running 1.8.4 SDK... 1.8.5 live instance using Python 2.7

Measurement is an NDB model... with a string property called status and a key property called asset....

(Deep in my handler code.... )

```
cursor=None
limit=10
asset_key = <a key to an actual asset>
qry = Measurement.query(
   Measurement.status=='PENDING', 
   Measurement.asset=asset_key)
results, cursor, more = qry.fetch_page(page_size=limit, start_cursor=cursor)
```

Now the weird thing is if I run this sometimes I get 4 items and sometimes only 1. (the right answer is 4)....

The dump of the query is exactly the same ... cursor is set to None... limit is always the same....same handler...same query and no new records in between each query. Fresh instance (eg 1st time + no other users)

Each query is only separated by seconds yet results a different.

Am I missing something here... has anyone else experienced this? Is this some sort of corrupt index? (It is a relatively large "table" with 482,911 items) Is NDB caching a cursor variable???

Very very odd.

Answer (score 0):

Queries do not look up values in any cache. However, query results are written back to the in-context cache if the cache policy says so (as per the docs). https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#incontext

Perhaps review the caching policy for the entity in question. However, from your snippet I'm unsure if your query is strongly consistent. That is more likely the cause of this issue: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency

Comment: Thanks for the response. Caching isn't a factor but I think your comment on consistency appears right. 

Going over our logs there was a number of "slow" datastore activities that day. What I find intriguing is that the inconsistent results were...well...inconsistent. I guess it shows that the RPC request to the datastore was handled by a number of servers each with a different idea of what the data was. Funny though that I would have thought that was avoidable using transactions (which it is in)... but now we have this insight hopefully we can work out an alternative solution (eg your link)